# How to produce sequential values between two numbers for multiple rows?

Tags: r

I have two columns, and the difference of the columns in another, as such:

```
df <- data.frame(start_value = c(111000, 839201, 667293, 198374),
                 end_value = c(111006, 839212, 667300, 198379))
```

What I'd like is to create separate columns that have the next value after start_value until end_value is met (aka until the difference between two columns is met), for each row. like this:

```
new_df <- data.frame(start_value = c(111000, 839201, 667293, 198374),
                     second_value = c(111001, 839202, 667294, 198375),
                     third_value = c(111002, 839203, 667295, 198376),
                     fourth_value = c(111003, 839204, 667296, 198377),
                     fifth_value = c(111004, NA, 667297, 198378), 
                     sixth_value = c(NA, NA, 667297, 198378), 
                     seventh_value = c(NA, NA, NA, 198379), 
                     end_value = c(111004, 667296, 667297, 198379))
```

The row names are negligible and can be anything. Basically, I just need to create rows that count starting from start_value until end_value.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the `end_value` column in `df` does not match that of `new_df`

Comment: You should think about not using a dataframe here. Maybe instead used a list for each generated sequence. The problem with a dataframe is if one sequence is longer than the others you will get alot of NAs

Answer (score 1):

```
cbind(df[1], plyr::rbind.fill.matrix(Map(function(x, y)t(seq(x, y)), df$start_value, df$end_value)), df[2])

  start_value      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11     12 end_value
1      111000 111000 111001 111002 111003 111004 111005 111006     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    111006
2      839201 839201 839202 839203 839204 839205 839206 839207 839208 839209 839210 839211 839212    839212
3      667293 667293 667294 667295 667296 667297 667298 667299 667300     NA     NA     NA     NA    667300
4      198374 198374 198375 198376 198377 198378 198379     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    198379
```

Using tidyverse:

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(dat = list(seq(start_value, end_value)))%>%
  unnest_wider(dat) %>%
  select(-end_value, everything(), end_value)
```

Comment: @taimishu you are using an older version of R. I have editted the answer. Try again

Answer (score 0):

A couple one-line options (returns a `data.frame`):

```
plyr::ldply(mapply(seq, df$start_value, df$end_value), rbind)
```

or base R (returns a matrix):

```
t(sapply(mapply(seq, df$start_value, df$end_value), "length<-", max(df$end_value - df$start_value + 1L)))
```